# websphere concurrent sessions

Tags: session, websphere, websphere-portal

I want to set maximum number of concurrent sessions for one user in IBM WebSphere Portal.

My goal is the following:

If any user logs in my application and the same user logs in from different machine, I want the second session to kill the first one.

Comment: Is it important that you actually kill the session or is it another end result you want to accomplish, such as whenever the user comes back in he/she must restart from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible with just configuring the portal properites, but we use Tivoli Access Manager for this (TAM) and WebSeal.

You could probably roll your own SessionListener and keep track of users IP-address in a map

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if you use a clustered environment with non-distributed sessions.
If you use distributed sessions you can eliminate an old sessions when a user logs in with a new session. This mechanism must be implemented by your code where you bind an authenticated user to the sessions created by that user.